# Cite a single InCollection without the "Eds." in apacite?

Tags: apacite

I am pretty new to LaTeX, so this will probably be a stupid question.

I am citing a number of chapters from Collections in my thesis. Today, my advisor criticized me for a minor flaw in my references. I have a reference like this:

```
   @InCollection{Example2010,
  author    = {Smith, John and Smith, Peter},
  title     = {A Nice Chapter},
  booktitle = {An Interesting Book},
  publisher = {Bielefeld University Press},
  year      = {2010},
  editor    = {John Smith and Peter Smith and Mary White and Other Dude},
  pages     = {261--310},
}
```

Apacite does the following:

Smith, J. & Smith, P. (2010). *A Nice Chapter*. In J. Smith, P. Smith, M. White & O. Dude (Eds.), An Interesting Book (pp. 261-310). Bielefeld University Press.

However, the people I listed as editors are not really the editors of the vorlume but all the authors that wrote chapters. Is there a way of getting rid of the "Eds." in this case without losing it for all the chapters in edited volumes i cite?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your writeup isn't exactly clear. If Smith, Smith, White, and Dude are *not* the actual editors, why do you list them in the `editor` field? Why don't you list the actual editors? Finally, if the actual editors can't be found, have you considered simply omitting the `editor` field?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote this a bit confusing: This is a book with chapters by different authors. All the authors of any of the chapters are listed on the cover, i still need to reference them. I just need a way to just say "J. Smith, P. Smith, M. White & O. Dude, An Interesting Book" in this case and leave out the word "Eds.". If this is possible.

Comment: If Smith, Smith, White, and Dude are listed on the book cover as the editors, they *are* the editors. In addition, if you're forced to use `apacite`-based bibliography formatting, I don't understand why you'd want to suppress the `(Eds.)` string. Otherwise, you'll have two separate groups of names, and your readers may well get confused as to what's going on.

Answer (score -1):

As I, like I said, need it like this and cannot really use the usual Stackoverflow

"I need to do A"

"Don't do A, it's bad to do A"

-thingy, i figured out a way how to do it and am just posting it if anyone should have the same problem and find this thread. I just deleted the "editor"-field and changed "booktitle" to

```
booktitle = {\emph{J. Smith, P. Smith, M. White & O. Dude,} An Interesting Book}
```

not elegant, works perfectly.